# PHP in-class construction?

Tags: php, class, constructor

I'm constructing PHP classes through one class, so they can individually be called, however, when calling from the main class, the variable is not found.

Such as:

```
init.php
    include('main_class.php');
    $main = new Main();

main_class.php
    include('sub_class.php');
    var $var;
    __construct() {
        $this->var = new Sub();
    }

sub_class.php
    __construct() {
        global $main;
        $main->var->function();
    }
```

The variable $main seems to not be initialized when called in sub_class.php, is the reason for this obvious, such as there's no possible way for this?

Comment: You are referencing the global variable $main before it exists. What I mean is, the constructor of sub_class is called when main_class.php is included; however, the $main variable isn't declared until after this inclusion.

Comment: I just realized that, which means I'm going to have to rewrite all of this, shame on me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. I'm not sure if you realize this, but $main stores an instance of the Main class, which in turn stores an instance of the Sub class in it's variable $var, which attempts to access the global reference to $main and access its variable $var, which is actually just a reference of the Sub class itself. In short, instead of calling $main->var->function(); you could simply call $this->function();

Comment: You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control